# How to construct api from json file nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, angular, api, express

I am trying to create API using node js from JSON file.

I have created a simple get request from Nodejs from the JSON file, which I am trying to remove unwanted data from json file and construct new response from that json file

My code as follows:

```
var express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const fs = require('fs');


const Test_Data = './data/testData.json';


app.get('/all', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(Test_Data, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          throw err;
      }

      res.send(JSON.parse(data));
  });
});

// finally, launch our server on port 3001.
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port %s...', server.address().port);
});
```

my testData.json as follows

```
[
    {
       "web-scraper-order": "1588668196-10",
       "web-scraper-start-url": "https://udemycoupon.learnviral.com/coupon-category/development/page/266",
       "pagenation": "",
       "pagenation-href": "",
       "courseid": "Redeem Offer",
       "courseidhref": "https://www.udemy.com/course/amazon-alexa-101-publishing-alexa-skills-without-coding/"
    },
    {
       "web-scraper-order": "1588668196-12",
       "web-scraper-start-url": "https://udemycoupon.learnviral.com/coupon-category/development/page/266",
       "pagenation": "",
       "pagenation-href": "",
       "courseid": "Redeem Offer",
       "courseidhref": "https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-complete-oracle-apps-r12-technical-training/?couponCode=TTROAP"
    }
]
```

in this testData.json file am getting unwanted data

am trying to create JSON response as follows

```
[
  {
     "id": "1",
     "courseTitle": "amazon alexa 101 publishing alexa skills without coding",
     "courseidhref": "https://www.udemy.com/course/amazon-alexa-101-publishing-alexa-skills-without-coding/"
  },
  {
     "id": "2",
     "courseTitle": "learn complete oracle apps r12 technical training",
     "courseidhref": "https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-complete-oracle-apps-r12-technical-training/?couponCode=TTROAP"
  }
]
```

am trying to create **courseTitle** from the **courseidhref**

for which i have done seprate code

```
var url = require('url');
var adr ='https://www.udemy.com/course/technology-strategy-success/?couponCode=05DISC2020';
var q = url.parse(adr, true);
var data = q.pathname.replace("/course/", '');
var output = data.replace("/", '');
console.log(output);
```

How can I combine both code to construct an json response from the JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let resData = [
    {
       "web-scraper-order": "1588668196-10",
       "web-scraper-start-url": "https://udemycoupon.learnviral.com/coupon-category/development/page/266",
       "pagenation": "",
       "pagenation-href": "",
       "courseid": "Redeem Offer",
       "courseidhref": "https://www.udemy.com/course/amazon-alexa-101-publishing-alexa-skills-without-coding/"
    },
    {
       "web-scraper-order": "1588668196-12",
       "web-scraper-start-url": "https://udemycoupon.learnviral.com/coupon-category/development/page/266",
       "pagenation": "",
       "pagenation-href": "",
       "courseid": "Redeem Offer",
       "courseidhref": "https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-complete-oracle-apps-r12-technical-training/?couponCode=TTROAP"
    }
] ;

let modifiedData = resData.map((val,ind)=>(
{
id : ind,
courseidhref:val.courseidhref,
courseTitle : val.courseidhref.split('?')[0].split('/').reverse()[1]
}
));
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvbNP.png)

Comment: courseTitle : val.courseidhref.replace('-', ' ').split('?')[0].split('/').reverse()[1]

i have tried to replace the (-) from the course ID  but its removing from first word alone 

courseTitle: 'learn complete-oracle-apps-r12-technical-training'

Comment: val.courseidhref.replace(/-/g, '  ').split('?')[0].split('/').reverse()[1]
use regex for global search of the ''-' character